# I have an error in testing my simple spring mvc service

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I create a new service with spring boot and spring mvc .

UserEntity.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity {

    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;
    private boolean login;

    public UserEntity(UserDto dto) {
        this.id = dto.getId();
        this.username = dto.getUsername();
        this.password = dto.getPassword();
        this.active = dto.isActive();
    }

    // getters&setters...
}
```

UserDto.class:

```
public class UserDto {

    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;

    public UserDto(long id, String username, String password, boolean active) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.active = active;
    }
    // getters&setters...
}
```

UserRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long> {

}
```

UserServiceImpl.class: (and UserService Interface)

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean saveUser(UserDto dto) {
        UserEntity user = new UserEntity(dto);
        repo.save(user);
        return true;
    }
}
```

UserController.class:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    private final UserService service;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void createUser(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        service.saveUser(userDto);
    }

}
```

Application.class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args);
    }

}
```

my Spring Boot project starts correctly. But when I test my service with IntelliJ Test Restful Web Service Tool I encounter an error:

[image]

Response:

```
 {"timestamp":1464066878392,"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/users"}
```

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: I think the repository should be `@Autowired`, not the constructor. Why do you even need a constructor for the UserServiceImpl when the repo is already Autowired?

Comment: Instead of only `@EnableAutoConfiguration` use `@SpringBootApplication`.  Without it there is no component scanning and no detection of your beans.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to remove the constructors from the UserController and UserServiceImpl classes, there's no need for them. Then, assign the `@Autowired` annotation to the declarations instead. Also, I don't think you need to make them `final`.

UserServiceImpl.class:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;

    @Override
    public boolean saveUser(UserDto dto) {
        UserEntity user = new UserEntity(dto);
        repo.save(user);
        return true;
    }
}
```

UserController.class:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired    
    private UserService service;

    public UserController(UserService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void createUser(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        service.saveUser(userDto);
    }
}
```

Comment: Constructor injection is to be preferred over field injection. Also moving from one to the other doesn't solve the problem.